# What is the difference between Debug and Unicode Debug in Visual Studio C++ project configuration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 whose available configurations are  Debug and Release. If I change the configurations to Unicode Debug and Unicode Release respectively, then what will be different? Will it make any problem? How I can change it?

Comment: Is this a debug issue or are you considering writing the program so it can be set to run in Ascii or Unicode mode, in which case, you need to use [tchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Cc842072.aspx) based types for variables and functions.

Comment: Make a new project. Do you see "Unicode Debug" and "Unicode Release" in that project? I don't in Visual Studio Express, but maybe they're there in the full version? I suspect they're defined by whoever created the project. And possibly they just define `UNICODE` and `UNICODE_` preprocessor symbols, which is the default anyway.

Comment: You can name a configuration anything you want.  It is just a name, it doesn't promise anything.  It is entirely up to you to change the appropriate settings.  With the most obvious approach that if you create a "Unicode Debug" configuration then you'd better change the Character Set setting for the "Debug" configuration from Unicode to Multi-byte.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the Unicode version will define the `UNICODE` preprocessor variable: this will cause all the generic char types TCHAR to become wchar_t (in ansi mode they are char).

Also, the unicode api functions are called instead of the ansi one (e.g. for `SetWindowText()` `SetWindowTextW` is called instead of `SetWindowTextA`)